# How to load children elements for CefBrowserWindow using UIA

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, ui-automation, chromium-embedded

I'm tring to automate a `Chrome Legacy Window`.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> element;
hr = automation_->ElementFromHandle((HWND)0x00871218, &element);

CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> resultTabElement;
hr = element->FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, resultTabPatternCondition, &resultTabElement);
```

But sometimes `resultTabElement` is empty. So I check the window using Inspect tool.

1. When the application just start up
   [image]
   Its ControlType is `UIA_PaneControlTypeId` and has no child nodes at this moment.
2. After I expend the second node in the red rectangle, and re-click the parent node of the red tangle:
   [image]
   Its ControlType is changed to `UIA_DocumentControlTypeId` and has child nodes.

So, do you know how this happens?

How do I progmatically reload the `Chrome Legacy Window` and change its type from `UIA_PaneControlTypeId` to `UIA_DocumentControlTypeId`?

---

Since the `Chrome Legacy Window` is changing for some reason, so I call `ElementFromHandle` on one of its ancestors, then I can get correct `resultTabElement` after the first call, although the first call is still not working just like Inspect tool.

Comment: Does *Chrome Legacy Window* belong to an old version of Chrome? Can you reproduce this issue on latest Chrome?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I guess it is an old version. It a 3rd-party software, I can not change it.